# Create associations after record creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I need to create 4 records in table `inventory` after creating a user. I know that i need to use callback `after_create`, but i guess it is not good according to the best practices and DRY principle to have 4 lines like this:

```
def create_items
    Item.create({user_id: self.id, item_id: 1})
    Item.create({user_id: self.id, item_id: 2})
    ...
end
```

Or maybe even like that?

```
def create_items
    self.inventories.create([
        {item_id: 1},
        {item_id: 2}
    ])
end
```

Comment: you can use a range "[*1..4].each do |i|"

Comment: @TopperH `id` is not in order :( Also, maybe i should use associations not to pass the user.id every time?

Comment: @TopperH Why not `(1..4).each do |i|`?

Comment: @tadman because i have to add items with id 24,85,90 and 11

Comment: @Src I meant as an alternative to the odd splatterized range inside an array approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ofen you can solve this with `has_many :through`:

```
class Inventory
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :item
end

class User
  has_many :inventories
  has_many :items, through: :inventories
end
```

Then you can add them straight-up:

```
items.each do |item|
  @user.items << item
end
```

If you have only ID values:

```
Item.where(id: ids).each do |item|
  @user.items << item
end
```

That's generally efficient enough to get the job done. If you're experiencing severe load problems with this you can always do it with a bulk-insert plugin, but that's usually a last-resort.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. My task is to add those items in Inventory for after creating user. How can i do that using code you written?

Comment: You can put that snippet of code anywhere you want, even in an `after_create` callback.

Comment: Oh, wait a second, now i got that) Thank's)

Comment: There is no need to iterate in the last example - you can use the shovel (<<)   operator to assign a whole array or collection. `@user.items << Item.where(id: ids)`